# Wifi stops working after update ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless

This is the information I get about my wireless card from running `lspci -nn`

```
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

Comment: SOLVED USING THIS THKS ANY WAY.
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

Answer (score 1):

> sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: THKS ANY WAY ALREADY SOLVED.

Comment: Does that package also install the binary driver? I ran into that one while doing my answer and was kind of iffy about it.

Comment: I am not sure, but this is how I have solved the issue in the past with the same card.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, says [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/213866) that you need to install some extra Broadcom-specific packages. Looks like there's a package specifically for your Broadcom card.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Of course, you'll need to either connect that computer with a wire or download the package from the Ubuntu [repository site](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/b/b43-fwcutter/firmware-b43-lpphy-installer_4.174.64.19-5_all.deb) and install it using `dpkg -i debfile`. Note: the package itself *may* try to download something from the internet, so try to get it on a wire if you can.

It appears that the package that you need to install is new in Quantal and more than likely upon upgrade it didn't install the specific package needed for you card.